# HTML Form Encryption via Java Class

Tags: java, javascript, html, encryption

I have a very simple example below to try and illustrate what I want to do.  My Java class "CommonUtils" has a method to encrypt and decrypt a string.  I want to encrypt  logonuidfield and logonpassfield before I write them to a cookie.  I understand calling CommonUtils.xorEncode(~) directly from Javascript is not possible, but is it possible to have a work around whereby the value of these fields are passed through CommonUtils.xorEncode(~) prior to the cookie being written?

I do not want to have the encryption method written in javascript.  I would prefer it to be in the done by the Java class.  My guess it that without using LiveConnect or some such, what I am trying to do is not possible.

Thanks in advance.

```
<%@ page import="package.CommonUtils" %>

<HTML>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JavaScript>
function setCookies() {
    var email = document.getElementById("logonuidfield").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("logonpassfield").value;

    writeCookie("EmailText",email);
    writeCookie("PasswordText",password);      
}

function writeCookie(name, value) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value);
}
</script>

<body>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%  
            String message = "This is a test message.";

            out.println("<Label>This is the original message: " + message + "</Label><br>");
            out.println("<Label>Hex before encrypting       : " + CommonUtils.printStringHex(message)  + "</Label><br>");
            message = CommonUtils.xorEncode(message);
            out.println("<Label>Hex after encrypting        : " + CommonUtils.printStringHex(message) + "</Label><br>");
            message = CommonUtils.xorDecode(message);
            out.println("<Label>Hex after decrypting        : " + CommonUtils.printStringHex(message) + "</Label><br>");
            out.println("<Label>This is the final message   : " + message + "</Label><br>");
        %>
    </td>
</tr>
<FORM name="logonForm" id="logonForm" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="setCookies()" method="post" action="" >
    <li>                                    
        <input type="text" id="logonuidfield" placeholder="email address*" style="width: 100%" name="j_user" type="email" value="" title="Email address *"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="password" id="logonpassfield" placeholder="Password*" style="width: 100%" name="j_password" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" name="uidPasswordLogon"/>
    </li>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? What's wrong with your code now?

Comment: Well the code as it is isn't encrypting the password in the cookie.  I am unsure how to get the password through the Java method and into the javascript.

Comment: Please post relevant bits from `CommonUtils`. Are the operations in-place or a new string is returned?

Comment: The methods just return a string which is basically an encrypted version of the String passed through as an argument:`public static String xorEncode(String data)
    {
      ...
      return new String(encryptedString);
    }`

Comment: What do your xorEncode and xorDecode methods look like? XOR encryption is trivial to break if the key is ever reused. Also, XOR encryption and decryption are supposed to be the same operation.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with your request/response cycle:

1. Client retrieves URL with form
2. Server compiles jsp and generates html output
3. Client sees empty form, no connection to the server exists, it's the "browser world".
4. Client submits the form, so you're posting the formdata to the server and saving cookies. At this point you have no way to run java code from the server, it's still "browser world".
5. Server receives the request and executes the jsp/servlet/whatever mapped in your form action, here you'r client has already sent the form data.
6. Server processes and sends a response.
7. Here the client receives again a response from the server and could save something the server processed to the cookies.

So, you cannot just do some java cyphering on server side on step 4 because you won't get the answer until step 7...

Maybe we need more specific information on what you're trying to do...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin.  I wasn't sure if the information provided was entirely sufficient.  I am trying to create a log on form for a site such that the log on form will remember the username and password as cookies.  However I do not want the password to be stored as plain text in the cookie.  I also do not want the encryption method to be a javascript method, since that can easily be viewed and hacked.

Comment: OK, so you don't really care that the password is encrypted in the communication channel (assume you will use ssl (https)). If that's the case, generate the encrypted cookie on the server after receiving the user/pwd (step 6) and send the response on step 7. So you will technically save the cookie one step after submitting the form. Think of it as better, so you will know that you will only store a cookie after a successful login. On the login form, you can validate if there's a cookie, if it is, submit it directly to the server.